# Can anyone tell me if this men or womens bike and possibly model?

Tags: mountain-bike

[image]

This bike is dirt cheap and fits my needs. I don't want to ask the seller too many questions and then discover the bike is worth more and not sell it. Im picking it up tomorrow for a steal. Question is this a girl bike and possibly does anyone know model outside scwhinn sierra? I cant find a similar picture of any bike so i cant I.D. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good work for making this question not a product valuation.

Comment: When was the last time you saw a woman with a skirt riding a bike?

Comment: For $10 why do you care if it a girl or guy bike?

Comment: @DanielRHicks I see women in skirts riding bikes daily, and I suspect that anybody who lives in a city where a lot of people commute by bike also does.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I haven't seen a woman with a skirt riding a bike in something like 10 years.  And it was only that one woman one would tend to see.  (I saw her again yesterday, but she wasn't wearing a skirt.)

Comment: Kind of looks like a suspension stem, you don't see those very often anymore

Comment: @DanielRHicks My girlfriend rides to work in skirts on a pretty regular basis.

Answer (score 6):

I see "Schwinn Sierra" in the decals your photo.  I'd guess its somewhere between 2000 and 2010 in age.

As long as it works, stops safely, isn't going to fail, then its a good bike to ride.

Yes, it would be classed as a woman's frame, but there's no physical reason a male couldn't ride it as well.   It may have a female-specific saddle or might be slightly angled up at the front, but that's easy to change.

There's suspension, but its in the seatpost, and possibly some in the handlebar stem (or its an adjustable stem)   The saddle is also sprung.

The black bar is a carrying adaptor for a car rack, replicating the higher top-tube of a men's bike.  Its not part of the bike and probably shouldn't be there for riding because its clamped to part of the handlebars that should turn freely.

Schwinn marketted very similar bikes under the models "Quest" and ["Mirada"](http://www.bicyclerainbow.com/mountain-bikes/schwinn-mirada-womens-mountain-bike-red.php) (that mirada is older than the one in your question)

The picture is not great so can't really comment on the bike's condition.

A $10 bike that does its job is totally worth it.  By the looks, you get lights too, which would cost that by themselves.

Comment: The chain rings look very worn to me (sharpened close to points though, as you say, one can't be sure because of the picture quality). A new set of chainringe probably costs more than the bike is worth.

Comment: It is a crude "mixte", which is neither a "man's" bike or a "women's" bike.  The mixte style was originally developed as a "gender-neutral" style but anymore it's often seen on "mountain" bikes, as it gives one more clearance if one must dismount suddenly on irregular terrain.  It's also convenient in other situations where one may need to dismount frequently.  (I say "crude" mixte since a true mixte has two tubes running all the way from the headset to the rear dropouts.)

Answer (score -1):

seems like a womens bike,judging by the geometry- reeally low head tube.Plus the cushioned saddle.

Comment: I agree about the geometry but your average entry-level bike in the US seems to come with that style of saddle regardless of whether it's aimed at men or women.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.